# What happened to Luke's green lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, the-last-jedi

When Luke goes to pay his nighttime call to Ben he uses his green lightsaber as a night light but it appears to be too bright and loud and so wakes Ben up.

[image: Luke wakes Ben up]

Throughout The Last Jedi I can't remember Luke having his green, or any, lightsaber with him.

Do we know where this lightsaber has gone?

Comment: I'd thought he had discarded it along with his X-wing.

Comment: @JaneS Was the X-wing discarded though? He could have just crashed it and seeing as he didn't want to leave he just didn't bother getting it out.

Comment: Dunno, any answer is speculation, I would close this as per our FWP but there’s a cloudy situation going on there.

Comment: I lol'd at "nightlight".

Comment: @Valorum -
 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01M2YE74Q/ref=asc_df_B01M2YE74Q5309664

Comment: @Valorum - it is funny, and the OP may be mistaken here....but they did use it that way in Clone Wars more than a few times.

Comment: I stumbled over an interview on episode 9(!) in which one of the makers was asked about the green lightsaber and answered something to the extent of "that may be something we want to explore... we are not in the habit of losing track of lightsabers ... [in the Star Wars universe]". Now I can't find that quote for the life of me. :(

Comment: @Marakai If that's true hopefully it's more than just oh here you are Rey here's another lightsaber.

Comment: +1 merely for the "certain point of view" description of the sequence of events in question!

Answer (score 6):

The last time we see it is when

> Luke and Ben fight at the school.

This leaves a number of possibilities:

1. It's been destroyed. Not convinced of this one.
2. Luke took it with him to Ahch-To, but didn't use it. It could be in his X-wing at the bottom of the bay, for example.
3. R2 has it. It wouldn't be the first time, and in Rey's vision in The Force Awakens you see Luke with R2, looking at what is most likely the school burning. Either Luke gave it to him, or being the ever-practical 'droid that we've come to know over nine films, he may have just picked it up himself. This is the one I'm thinking is most likely, personally.

And a couple that give away the above spoiler.

1. > Ben took it as a trophy. *That which does not kill me...* and all that. This is also less likely as he's much more interested in his grandfather than his uncle.
2. > It's still there, under the rubble of Ben's home. If Luke was that dis-spirited by what he had almost done with it, he may well have left it behind.

Comment: Hey. I edited your question to show the non-spoilers. We like questions and answers to be able to stand on their own without having to look at the spoilers if possible. This was possible with your answer, so I adjusted it.

Comment: Cool, no problem. I tend to err on the side of caution with spoilers. :)

Comment: For your spoilered number 1 I think it's less likely he doesn't have it as he would likely use that rather than an imperfect deign he has at the moment.

Comment: Oh, I agree that this is a less likely one, but equally, he has his own from that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

The movie does not indicate one way or another.

In the climactic showdown,

> Force-projected Luke

uses a blue lightsaber, which we are to assume was his recovered one.

> The same one that was destroyed during the showdown between Rey and Kylo Ren

The ultimate fate of Luke's green lightsaber (first seen in Return of the Jedi and last seen in his hands prior to his falling out with Ben) is unknown, but it is most likely either on the island where Rey found him or near the ruins of the school he built.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was really weird that it wasn't green during that scene, seems like it being the wrong color could have tipped off the enemy.  As an audience member I was thinking, "Hey, that's not right!"

Comment: @sirjonsnow - that was the intent of the director, I believe. On later viewings, knowing the result of the fight, you will pick up on the *many* clues that all is not as it seems, which Kylo (in his anger, fear, and single-minded rage) missed.  The big one for me was the salt, and how it didn't always change color.

Comment: @sirjonsnow - Could be that Kylo knows the fate of the green lightsaber as well in which case it makes no difference, it could even be Kenobi's saber